# How can I sync two s3 buckets with regex?

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have s3 bucket with many files (1m+).

I'd like to move these files to another one, but this time I want to have a bit more structure.

Is it possible to do something like:

`s3cmd sync s3://bucket1/foo2011-01-01* s3//bucket2/archive/events/2011-01-01/`

`s3cmd sync s3://bucket1/foo2011-01-02* s3//bucket2/archive/events/2011-01-02/`

Answer (score 2):

The `s3cmd` is rather old. I recommend that you use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

It has a `sync` command that can specify filename patterns to include/exclude. This should suit your needs.

See: [CLI sync command documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)